# Treeview shows random extra space

Tags: wpf, xaml, treeview

I have a treeview in wpf that is showing some strange behavior (at least I think it's strange).  I don't see anywhere I can attach an image but basically on some of the items it looks like it's double spaced or has an extra 3px or so margin and on some it looks like it's single spaced.  Here is the XAML defining it:

```
        <TreeView Margin="5,0,0,5" ItemsSource="{Binding SortedCategories}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type COBie:CategoryData}" ItemsSource="{Binding SortedTypes}">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding AnyChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" Content="{Binding CategoryName}" IsEnabled="{Binding HasTypes}" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type COBie:InstanceData}">
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding isChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" Content="{Binding ElemID}" />
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type COBie:TypeData}">
                    <TreeViewItem IsEnabled="{Binding HasInstances}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                        <TreeViewItem.Header>
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding isChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" Content="{Binding ElemName}" />
                        </TreeViewItem.Header>
                        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SortedInstances}">
                            <ListView.View>
                                <GridView>
                                    <GridViewColumn>
                                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding isChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    </GridViewColumn>
                                    <GridViewColumn Header="ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ElemID}" />
                                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ElemName}" />
                                    <GridViewColumn Header="Mark" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Mark}" />
                                    <GridViewColumn Header="Room" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding RoomDisplay}" />
                                </GridView>
                            </ListView.View>
                        </ListView>
                    </TreeViewItem>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TreeView.Resources>
        </TreeView>
```

The only other relevant style that would apply is:

```
        <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded}" />
        </Style>
```

I don't see anywhere that defines a margin at all and even if it did all of the elements are of the same class so it should apply to all equally.

Anyone know what is going on?

Comment: Also I went through and checked the ElemName values for items that were and were not showing the extra space and neither has extra spaces or line feeds in the value of the ElemName property (which is what is being displayed...

Comment: Ok I still don't understand why this is happening.  I tried hard coding the height of the checkbox in the header, margin remained.  Since it really looks like a margin I tried hard coding the margin to 0, no change.  I did find a work around however.  If instead of using Content={Binding ElemName} in the checkbox definition I expanded it to <Checkbox><Textblock Text="{Binding ElemName}" /></Checkbox> and it looks normal.  I'm not sure why, but that worked...  If anyone can shed some light on why the second worked and not the first I will mark it as the answer...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had the same issue, that there were seemingly random gaps.
After looking closer I found out that the gaps appeared around items, that have underscore(s) in the name.

If you put the string directly in the content property of the CheckBox and it contains underscores, the CheckBox will surround a TextBlock with a Control named AccessText, probably to support short cut keys (similar to underscores in Button's Content property).

Now for some reason the Margin of the Checkbox is set on the TextBlock perfectly fine, if there is no AccessText involved, but is not set on the TextBlock inside the AccessText. This way the TextBlock inside the AccessText will have default TextBlock Style, which in my case was with Margin=5.

I guess in your case it must be a closely related issue.

Comment: Huh, interesting.  I have since moved on from this and used the textblock trick and the UI as been revised a bit anyway but I will try it out when I can.  However since you are the only one to answer I will go ahead and mark it as the answer :)